# Montando matriz tabela no Django

Tags: django, matriz

Eu tenho duas tabelas, no exemplo (qualquer) da figura abaixo
eu tenho a tabela `Paises` e a tabela `Energia`

[image: http://www.biodieselbr.com/i/energia/custo-geracao-energia.gif]

Montando uma terceira tabela no Django eu teria algo com os campos

```
pais, energia, valor

Áustria, Carvão, 3.6

Áustria, Ciclo combinado de gás, 3.4
```

e assim por diante.

**Pergunta:** Como eu montaria essa tabela no template da forma que está na imagem?

Edited:

@mgibsonbr Eu adaptei para meu modelo, veja o código abaixo.

```
def quotation_list(request):
    stores = list(Store.objects.all())
    products = list(Product.objects.all())
    # indice
    index_store = {store.id: index for index, store in enumerate(stores)}
    index_product = {product.id: index for index,
                     product in enumerate(products)}
    # dados para o template
    cabecalho = ["Lojas"] + [store.store for store in stores]
    linhas = [([product.product] + [None for store in stores])
              for product in products]

    for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
        linhas[index_store[pev.store_id]][
            index_product[pev.product_id]] = pev.price
```

Mas deu o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alias, como eu faço para retornar os itens no contexto para renderizar na página? Ficou faltando o `return`.

Comment: Quais são seus models? País e Energia? Não há nenhuma relação entre esses dois models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu recomendaria tratar seus dados no *view* antes de mandar pro template:

```
paises = list(Paises.objects.all())    # Filtre e ordene como achar melhor
energias = list(Energia.objects.all()) # idem

# Auxiliares
indices_pais = { pais.id:indice for indice,pais in enumerate(paises) }
indices_energia = { energia.id:indice for indice,energia in enumerate(energias) }

# Dados para o template
cabecalho = ["País"] + [energia.nome for energia in energias]
linhas = [( [pais.nome] + [None for energia in energias] ) for pais in paises]

for pev in PaisEnergia.objects.all(): # Filtre conforme os países e energias usados
    linhas[indices_pais[pev.pais_id]][indices_energia[pev.energia_id]+1] = pev.valor
```

Então você enviaria `cabecalho` e `linhas` para o template e renderizaria como uma tabela. Note que se algum dado país/energia estiver ausente ele aparecerá como `None` (você pode customizar isso na criação de `linhas`).

Exemplo de como isso poderia ser renderizado num template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for item in cabecalho %}
            <th>{{ item }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for linha in linhas %}
        <tr>
        {% for item in linha %}
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lembrando que se você quiser dar um destaque pra primeira coluna por exemplo (o nome do país) você pode fazer isso usando `forloop.first`, ou talvez se você quiser as linhas com cores alternadas (para legibilidade) pode usar `forloop.counter`, etc.

```
    {% for linha in linhas %}
        <tr class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}cinza{% else %}azul{% endif %}">
        {% for item in linha %}
            <td{% if forloop.first %} class="bold"{% endif %}>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Eu editei minha pergunta, pois gerou um erro.

Comment: Creio que você inverteu os índices ao adaptar a resposta. Experimente `linhas[index_product[pev.product_id]][index_store[pev.store_id]] = pev.price`

Comment: P.S. Além disso tinha faltado um `+1` na resposta original (pois o nome do país ocupa a posição `0` da lista). Corrigido, fica `linhas[index_product[pev.product_id]][index_store[pev.store_id]+1] = pev.price`

Comment: e qual é o return da função, ou o que eu devo levar para o contexto para ser renderizado na página?

Comment: além disso como eu monto no template? o laço no caso?

Comment: `cabecalho` e `linhas`. Grosso modo, você abre o `table`, o `thead` e o `tr` e itera sobre `cabecalho` (um `th` por item); depois você fecha estes e abre o `tbody`; itera sobre linhas, um `tr` por linha, e em cada linha você itera sobre os itens (um `td` por item); por fim fecha o `tbody` e o `table`. Para uma tabela simples seria isso.

Comment: complementado sua resposta: como eu posso colocar mais o campo `quantity` na linha? Eu tentei `for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
        linhas[index_product[pev.product_id]][
            index_store[pev.store_id] + 1] = pev.quantity` mas não foi.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Cada produto tem um preço e uma quantidade? Se for isso, use uma tupla: `... = (pev.price, pev.quantity)`. E no template: `for price, quantity in linha`. Aí você usa as variáveis `price` e `quantity` em vez de `item`.

Comment: Thank you again.............

Comment: faltou mais uma coisinha: `product` que havia inserido antes? Onde ele fica, porque agora ele sumiu, e mesmo que eu coloque pev.product ele não aparece, e antes ele era o índice 0 da lista de cada linha, agora ele não aparece mais.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Ah, claro, o primeiro índice é diferente dos outros... Bom, a coisa já está complicando um pouco, mas você pode começar fazendo com que o primeiro elemento também seja uma tupla de tamanho 2 - `linhas = [( [(pais.nome,None)] + [None for energia in energias] ) for pais in paises]` - pro `for` continuar funcionando - e então dar tratamento especial pro primeiro item - usando `forloop.first` como sugerido. Se isso não for suficiente, e você quiser que eu explique melhor, por favor abra uma nova pergunta, pois esta já está quase virando uma "pergunta camaleão" hehe :)

Comment: agora já está suficiente, não vou complicar mais não. Agora já entendi sua lógica. Valeu.