# Retornando o valor mínimo para comparação em template Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Em continuação a uma resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96503/761

```
def quotation_list(request):
    stores = list(Store.objects.all())
    products = list(Product.objects.all())
    # indice
    index_store = {store.id: index for index, store in enumerate(stores)}
    index_product = {product.id: index for index,
                     product in enumerate(products)}
    # dados para o template
    cabecalho = ["Lojas"] + [store.store for store in stores]
    linhas = [([product.product] + [None for store in stores])
              for product in products]

    for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
        linhas[index_product[pev.product_id]][
            index_store[pev.store_id] + 1] = pev.price

    minimos = {}

    for linha in linhas:
        minimos[linha[0]] = min(linha[1:])

    context = {'cabecalho': cabecalho, 'linhas': linhas, 'minimos': minimos}
    return render(request, 'core/quotation_list.html', context)
```

Este trecho

```
minimos = {}

for linha in linhas:
    minimos[linha[0]] = min(linha[1:])
```

retorna no template o seguinte resultado:

```
{% for linha in linhas %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ minimos }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

retorna:

{'milho 500 g': Decimal('1.32'), 'chocolate em pó 500 g': Decimal('2.92'), 'sabonete 1 pcte': Decimal('1.87'), 'cerveja 350 ml': Decimal('2.49'), 'detergente 500 ml': Decimal('2.26'), 'grão de bico 500 g': Decimal('2.21'), 'sabão em barra 100 g': Decimal('2.97'), 'queijo mussarela 500 g': Decimal('1.86'), 'feijão 1 Kg': Decimal('4.43'), 'desinfetante 1 l': Decimal('3.58'), 'absorvente 1 pcte': Decimal('2.68'), 'pão integral 1 pcte': Decimal('2.41'), 'creme dental 1 unid': Decimal('1.34'), 'refrigerante 350 ml': Decimal('2.81'), 'suco integral 1 l': Decimal('3.99'), 'amendoim 500 g': Decimal('2.41'), 'café em pó 1 Kg': Decimal('1.65'), 'água mineral 1.5 l': Decimal('2.22'), 'refrigerante 1.5 l': Decimal('4.75'), 'água sanitária 1 l': Decimal('3.72'), 'leite 1 l': Decimal('1.63'), 'arroz 5 Kg': Decimal('3.16'), 'fralda M 1 pcte': Decimal('1.54'), 'sabão em pó 1 Kg': Decimal('3.58'), 'shampoo 350 ml': Decimal('2.97')}
{'milho 500 g': Decimal('1.32'), 'chocolate em pó 500 g': Decimal('2.92'), 'sabonete 1 pcte': Decimal('1.87'), 'cerveja 350 ml': Decimal('2.49'), 'detergente 500 ml': Decimal('2.26'), 'grão de bico 500 g': Decimal('2.21'), 'sabão em barra 100 g': Decimal('2.97'), 'queijo mussarela 500 g': Decimal('1.86'), 'feijão 1 Kg': Decimal('4.43'), 'desinfetante 1 l': Decimal('3.58'), 'absorvente 1 pcte': Decimal('2.68'), 'pão integral 1 pcte': Decimal('2.41'), 'creme dental 1 unid': Decimal('1.34'), 'refrigerante 350 ml': Decimal('2.81'), 'suco integral 1 l': Decimal('3.99'), 'amendoim 500 g': Decimal('2.41'), 'café em pó 1 Kg': Decimal('1.65'), 'água mineral 1.5 l': Decimal('2.22'), 'refrigerante 1.5 l': Decimal('4.75'), 'água sanitária 1 l': Decimal('3.72'), 'leite 1 l': Decimal('1.63'), 'arroz 5 Kg': Decimal('3.16'), 'fralda M 1 pcte': Decimal('1.54'), 'sabão em pó 1 Kg': Decimal('3.58'), 'shampoo 350 ml': Decimal('2.97')}

**Pergunta**: Eu preciso fazer uma comparação, ou seja, este é o menor valor de cada linha de produto, ou seja, o produto mais barato.

Dai eu tentei

```
{% if minimos == item %}
    <td style="color: red;">{{ item }}</td>
{% else %}
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
{% endif %}


{% for item in linha %}
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Para comparar o menor valor de cada linha e destacá-lo em vermelho.

Mas não estou conseguindo retornar corretamente o menor valor a partir do dicionário mínimos para fazer isso.

Como corrigir isso?

De novo, eu preciso saber qual é o menor valor de cada linha e pintá-lo de vermelho.

Resultado esperado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Não dá pra fazer um `zip` no template](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=django%20template%20zip) (i.e. iterar sobre duas ou mais listas simultaneamente), então eu sugiro fazer isso também no view antes de mandar pra lá:

```
minimos = [] # Em vez de mapear, usa o mesmo índice da linha

for linha in linhas:
    minimos.append(min(linha[1:]))

                                   # Junta linhas e mínimos numa lista de pares (tuplas)
context = {'cabecalho': cabecalho, 'linhas_minimos': zip(linhas, minimos)}
```

E no template:

```
{% for linha, minimo in linhas_minimos %}
<tr>
    {% for item in linha %}
        {% if minimo == item %}
            <td style="color: red;">{{ item }}</td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: mgibsonbr Thank you.

Comment: Deixei uma imagem para compartilhar com todos o resultado esperado, e alcançado. Obrigado.