# Total e subtotal em template do django usando listas

Tags: django, django-templates

Como eu faço para calcular o subtotal e o total por loja (store) na view para jogar os resultados no template? No caso estou usando listas.

```
def quotation_list(request):
    stores = list(Store.objects.all())
    products = list(Product.objects.all())
    # indice
    index_store = {store.id: index for index, store in enumerate(stores)}
    index_product = {product.id: index for index,
                     product in enumerate(products)}
    # dados para o template
    cabecalho = ["Lojas"] + [store.store for store in stores]
    linhas = [([product.product] + [None for store in stores])
              for product in products]

    for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
        total = pev.price * pev.quantity
        linhas[index_product[pev.product_id]][index_store[pev.store_id] +
                                              1] = (pev.price, pev.quantity, total, pev.store, pev.product)

    # retorna o menor preço de cada produto
    # a quantidade, total e loja também estão nesta lista
    mais_barato = []
    for linha in linhas:
        mais_barato.append(min(linha[1:]))

    # destaca os menores preços no template
    mb = 0
    if request.GET.get('mais_barato', False):
        mb = 1

    # mostra somente os menores preços
    smb = 0
    if request.GET.get('somente_mais_barato', False):
        smb = 1
```

Repare que aqui eu ordeno a lista por loja.

```
    # mostra os produtos mais baratos, a quantidade e o total
    bqt = 0
    if request.GET.get('quantidade_e_total', False):
        mais_barato = sorted(mais_barato,
                             key=lambda store: str(store[3]))  # sort by store
        bqt = 1

    context = {
        'cabecalho': cabecalho,
        'linhas_mais_barato': zip(linhas, mais_barato),
        'mb': mb,
        'smb': smb,
        'bqt': bqt,
    }
    return render(request, 'core/quotation_list.html', context)
```

Eu tentei algo semelhante a isto aqui

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22366344/802542

mas não deu certo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr vai que é tua Marcelo Gibson. :)

Comment: Eu não entendi essa sua ordenação. Você está ordenando por loja, simplesmente? Tipo, em ordem alfabética ou coisa assim? Se for o caso, seria mais fácil fazer isso logo no início, i.e. `stores = list(Store.objects.all().order_by("store"))`. Agora, se o que você quer é reordenar as colunas de modo que as lojas com o total mais barato apareçam na frente, isso é um pouquinho mais complicado (pois você precisaria manter `cabecalho` e `linhas` consistente durante essa ordenação).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi se o subtotal se refere às linhas, colunas, ou ambos, então vou responder para "ambos" (ainda que no seu caso particular isso não faça sentido).

Para calcular o subtotal da linha, acrescente um elemento a mais em cada linha. Para calcular o subtotal da coluna, acrescente uma linha a mais. Durante o preenchimento (quando você itera sobre a tabela de relacionamentos), você vai atualizando os valores dos subtotais em um e outro caso:

```
cabecalho = ["Lojas"] + [store.store for store in stores] + ["Subtotal"]
linhas= [([product.product] + [None for store in stores] + [(0,0,0,None,product.product)])
            for product in products
        ] +
        [["Subtotal"] + [(0,0,0,store.store,None) for store in stores] + [(0,0,0,None,None)]]

def soma_tuplas(a, b):
    return (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2], a[3], a[4])

for pev in Quotation.objects.all():
    total = pev.price * pev.quantity

    i0 = index_product[pev.product_id]
    i1 = index_store[pev.store_id] + 1
    valor = (pev.price, pev.quantity, total, pev.store, pev.product)

    linhas[i0][i1] = valor

    # Subtotal da linha (se fizer sentido no seu caso)
    linhas[i0][len(stores)+1] = soma_tuplas(linhas[i0][len(stores)+1], valor)

    # Subtotal da coluna (se fizer sentido no seu caso)
    linhas[len(produtos)][i1] = soma_tuplas(linhas[len(produtos)][i1], valor)

    # Total da tabela (se fizer sentido no seu caso)
    linhas[len(produtos)][len(stores)+1] = 
        soma_tuplas(linhas[len(produtos)][len(stores)+1], valor)
```

Se eu entendi bem o que você está modelando, apenas os subtotais por coluna fazem sentido no seu caso, e o valor que vai te interessar no final é a soma dos totais (i.e. soma das quantidades vezes preço de todos os produtos de uma loja) - ou seja, o índice `2` da tupla. Mas dei uma resposta completa caso alguém no futuro ache essa pergunta útil.

Detalhe: se fizer desse jeito, você não precisa mexer no `mais_barato`, pois ele vai calcular o mínimo dos subtotais também. :)

---

**Adendo:** Na [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102144/215) eu havia sugerido usar `zip` para unir `linhas` e `mais_barato` - o que é uma solução rápida pro caso de [iterar sobre duas listas ao mesmo tempo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31476020/520779). Mas se você for ordenar um ou outro, é importante manter os elementos juntos, do contrário os valores de cada linha não corresponderão aos valores dos mínimos:

```
linhas_mais_barato = zip(linhas, mais_barato) # Primeiro faz o zip, depois ordena

# mostra os produtos mais baratos, a quantidade e o total
bqt = 0
if request.GET.get('quantidade_e_total', False):
    linhas_mais_barato = sorted(linhas_mais_barato,
                                key=lambda store: str(store[1][3]))  # sort by store
    bqt = 1

context = {
    'cabecalho': cabecalho,
    'linhas_mais_barato': linhas_mais_barato,
```

(não sei se isso está certo, nem se o que você queria na verdade era ordenar por coluna e não por linha, mas o importante seja como for é manter `linhas` e `mais_barato` consistentes entre si)

Comment: Perfect!!! O subtotal era somente por linha (por loja ('store')). Mas sua resposta ficou bem completa. E o adendo também foi considerado. Valeu mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Deixei uma [imagem](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102144/retornando-o-valor-m%C3%ADnimo-para-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-template-django) para compartilhar com todos o resultado esperado, e alcançado. Obrigado.

Comment: Só mais uma coisinha, no meu caso, eu não quero o subtotal da linha. `linhas[i0][len(stores) + 1]` como eu faço para tirá-lo? Eu tentei identificá-lo pelo seu índice para tirá-lo apenas no template, mas não deu certo. No momento estou usando
`{% for linha, mais_barato in linhas_mais_barato %} - {% for item in linha %} - <td>{{ item }}</td>`

Comment: eu tive que editar a pergunta a partir do **adendo**, pois ela não estava bem elaborada, e não retornou o resultado esperado. Quer dizer, sua solução foi útil, mas não consegui retornar o que eu esperava a partir da reedição da minha pergunta. Favor ler a partir do **adendo**. Valeu.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva Isso muda bastante a pergunta, num caso a tabela é Produto x Loja, no outro vejo que a tabela é de produtos e loja é uma coluna. Não dá pra adaptar a resposta, sugiro abrir outra pergunta pra isso. Inclusive eu usaria uma estratégia diferente para esse caso, uma que fizesse o trabalho pesado no próprio BD e não na *view*. Agora estou sem tempo, mais tarde um pouco explico melhor.