# Deixando toda a coluna destacada (Django + template)

Tags: django, template

Estou tentando deixar toda a coluna colorida, mas somente a última linha é que está ficando.

Tentei toda a lógica possível, mas não estou conseguindo acertar.

Este post é uma continuação de [Total e subtotal em template do django usando listas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102214/total-e-subtotal-em-template-do-django-usando-listas).

## views.py

```
...
    # loja mais barata
    loja_mais_barata = min(linhas[-1][1:])[3]
...
```

## template.html

```
<tbody>
{% for linha, mais_barato in linhas_mais_barato %}
  {% if linha.0 == 'Subtotal' %}
    <tr class="info" style="font-weight: bold;">
  {% else %}
    <tr>
  {% endif %}
    {% for item in linha %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
      {% elif forloop.last %}
      {% else %}
        {% if item.3 == loja_mais_barata %}
          <td>OK</td>
        {% else %}
          <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.2 }}</td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
  <tr>
    {% for item in cabecalho %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <th>   </th>
      {% else %}
        <td class="text-center">Preço</td>
        <td class="text-center">Quant.</td>
        <td class="text-center" style="border-right: 1px dashed #333;">Total</td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {% for item in cabecalho %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <th>{{ item }}</th>
      {% else %}
        <th class="text-center"></th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ item }}</th>
        <th class="text-center"></th>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @mgibsonbr acho que este negócio não vai ter fim. Mas eu acho que este é o último. hehe

Comment: Você sabe que eu *não sou* notificado quando você usa @ numa pergunta que eu não participei, né? :P (se eu não achar sua pergunta sozinho, eu nem vou ficar sabendo que ela existe...)

Comment: É essa linha que não está funcionando como devia? `{% if item.3 == loja_mais_barata %}` Sua lógica me parece correta, não consigo enxergar onde pode estar o erro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Feliz Natal. Então parece correto sim, mas ele não está colorindo a coluna toda :(